# Issues with using unsupported Win32 GDI Pens modes?

Tags: windows, winapi, drawing, gdi

The MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535223(VS.85).aspx) is (somewhat) clear about the following two facts about GDI Pens:

1. A Cosmetic pen (create via CreatePen or ExtCreatePen w/ PS_COSMETIC) must be 1 *unit* wide  (well, <= 1, but let's not go there).
2. <strike>A Geometric (ExtCreatePen w/ PS_GEOMETRIC) pen must solid (PS_SOLID only, no PS_DASH, etc). They can, however, draw fatter lines.</strike> *This is clearly documented in the link I put above as only a 9x restriction (I'm dumb). To my defense (bad) comments and (broken) logic in my code led me to believe otherwise. Some other googled articles must have been written concidering only Windows 9x.*

**Why can I voilate these rules and have GDI happily draw with these Pens?**

I can create fat (width = 10, for example) cosmetic pens **and** dashed Geometric pens. Heck, I can create a fat, dashed geometric pen!

These Pens seem to work fine *usually*. The only problem I've seen is in Polyline when I pass very large arrays of points - it renders the lines very slowly. However, Polyline is acting strangely with large arrays in general - it justs acts differently with the *bad* pens. (my other polyline problems may be another question...)

**Is it ever safe to use wide Cosmetic pens <strike>or wide Geometric with patterns?</strike>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should adhere to the documented API, otherwise you risk relying on OS version specific behaviour.

The `ExtCreatePen` restrictions you describe (e.g, no `PS_DASH` with `PS_GEOMETRIC`) only apply to Win9x, not WinNT, so on NT/2000/XP your "fat, dashed geometric pen" shouldn't be a problem. Also note that [`Polyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534241.aspx) has some limitations on Win9x.

If you want dashed lines, I'd suggest using `PS_USERSTYLE` so that you control the lengths of the dashes and gaps, rather than relying on whatever default `PS_DASH` gives you.

Comment: While I know I should follow the docs, released code is already not following the rules. I was hoping for insight on why this works - or won't work (how quickly does the patch need to be released). However,pointing out the geometric mistake on my part is good enough for me to accept this!

Comment: My polyline problems will be another question - I can crash windows with the call by passing large arrays even on modern versions of Windows (Vista)...

Comment: @Aardvark - I'm afraid I can't give you any more insight, I was only going by what the docs say.